# Python - использование super для добавления параметров в субклассе

Tags: python, классы

Имеются 2 класса, класс Student наследует метод get_full_info от Person. Каким образом с помощью super() добавить к этому методу атрибут university не переопределяя полностью этот метод? (как это сделано у меня)

```
class Person():

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, status):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.status = status


    def get_full_info(self):

        return "{}, {}, {}, {}".format(self.name, self.surname, self.age, 
self.status)
```

---

```
from person import Person

class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, status, university):
        super().__init__(person, name, surname, age, status)
        self.university = university

    def get_full_info(self):

        return "{}, {}, {}, {}, {}".format(self.name, self.surname, self.age, self.status, self.university)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get_full_info(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return super().get_full_info() + ", {}".format(self.university)
```